# jenkins behind nginx in kubernetes

Tags: curl, jenkins, kubernetes

I have a jenkins server behind a Kubernetes (AWS ELB - NGINX proxy ). When I try to trigger a remote job using `curl` it fails:

```
# curl -X POST -H "$CRUMB" "https://jenkins:add91b3fefefefefef@jenkins.subdomain.domain.io/job/Excercise1/buildWithParameters?token=8buX7dddskddf&EMAIL=sfff@test.com&USER=muj"
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like SSL certificate issue, Try using `-k` option with `curl` to skip ssl verification

```
# curl -X POST -k -H "$CRUMB" "https://jenkins:add91b3fefefefefef@jenkins.subdomain.domain.io/job/Excercise1/buildWithParameters?token=8buX7dddskddf&EMAIL=sfff@test.com&USER=muj"
```

Comment: im getting this now                                                                                                                    <html>
<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.13.12</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `308 Permanent Redirect` redirect status response code indicates that the resource requested has been definitively moved to the URL given by the **Location** headers.  Try using `-ivvv` to print Headers as well and found out where the resource have been now moved to

Comment: its not giving any thing specific,, see basically my jenknis is running in a kubernetes pod behind AWS ELB and Nginx Proxy,, although i can access jenknis thru its url globally,,only triggering job is not happening!

Comment: resolved it with -L option